# null measurement sections in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Hi I am seeing in class Fubini's theorem in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and I ran into this problem:

> $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n\times [c,d]$ is a compact. If defined $\forall y\in [c,d]$, $U_y=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: (x,y)\in U\}$ and $\forall y\in [c,d]$ has $\mu(U_y)=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ then $\mu(U)=0$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.

Note: Using the Fubini theorem the statement is true, but my question is if possible try using definition of sets of measure zero

Comment: Suffice to prove that $\pi_1(U)=\bigcup_{y\ \in \ [c,d]} U_y$ has measure zero. As $U_y$ is a compact $\forall y\in [c,d]$ given $\varepsilon >0$ there exists an open $V_y$ such that $U_y \subset V_y$ and $\mu(V_y)< \varepsilon$ then $\pi_1(U) \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{k} V_{y_i}$ with $\mu(\bigcup_{i=1}^{k} V_{y_i})<k\varepsilon$ the problem is now in control of $k$ , maybe someone can suggest a way to accomplish this?

Comment: There is a proof of this special case of fubini's theorem in the appendix of the book "differential topology" by Guillemin and Pollack.

Comment: Tim kinsella: very grateful!